# Python Mapscript 6.0.1 layer.getShape API

Tags: python, mapserver, mapscript

I am attempting to follow the mapscript example described here - http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/wiki/RasterQuery

but ran into some trouble with

```
s = layer.getShape(result.shapeindex, result.tileindex)
```

It appears that this no longer works

```
In [63]: s = layer.getShape(result.shapeindex, result.tileindex)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/calvin/work/luc/<ipython-input-63-969295303151> in <module>()
----> 1 s = layer.getShape(result.shapeindex, result.tileindex)

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MapScript-6.0.1-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/mapscript.pyc in getShape(self, *args)
   1395     def nextShape(self): return _mapscript.layerObj_nextShape(self)
   1396     def close(self): return _mapscript.layerObj_close(self)
-> 1397     def getShape(self, *args): return _mapscript.layerObj_getShape(self, *args)
   1398     def getNumResults(self): return _mapscript.layerObj_getNumResults(self)
   1399     def getResultsBounds(self): return _mapscript.layerObj_getResultsBounds(self)

TypeError: layerObj_getShape() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

What is the argument I ought to supply to getShape method to get it working again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EPIC FAIL**: I apologize, I just found out that the documentation I mentioned is not up to date.

The correct API (taken from the swig interface [file](http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/browser/trunk/mapserver/mapscript/swiginc/layer.i#L196)) is the following:

```
shape=layer.getShape(result)
```

where result is the resultObj returned by [getResult](http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/browser/trunk/mapserver/mapscript/swiginc/layer.i#L229).

Opened [ticket](http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/ticket/4139) and updated documentation (will go live soon).

**DOCUMENTATION mentioned in the answer below IS OUTDATED**

---

The mapscript API for **layerObj** is fully documented here:

http://mapserver.org/mapscript/mapscript.html#layerobj

by reading it one finds out that *getShape* has been deprecated in favor of *getFeature* (which takes exactly two arguments, while getShape requires three, the first of them being a shapeObj).

So your code should be:

```
s = layer.getFeature(result.shapeindex, result.tileindex)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same with php

ex. $oRes = $oLayer->getResult($iRes);

```
$oShape = $oLayer->getShape($oRes); 
//instead of  $oShape = $oLayer->getShape($oRes->tileindex,$oRes->shapeindex);
```